# Not able to show node comments on a view -content pane

Tags: 7, views, panels

I' a bit stuck with this. I am using panels in Drupal 7. I have created a new content type. I am crating a page (page manager) and I am using a view content pane inside a panel in the page. In that view I am filtering nodes of that particular content type I created. I am not using fields but the full content of the node and I can't figure it out why it doesn't show comments. If I change to page view, for example, I can see the comments, but not using content pane.

What am I missing? Might it be something about the template?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with comments in views for a while. It seems there is a kind of bug as checking "Display comments" on the Full content settings doesn't seem to work. You can solve this, using display suite as the format used by views, which comes with the option "Comments -load comments for every node to display" which does work as expected.

I hope it can help to someone else in the future. :-)